# In Ansible dynamic inventory JSON, can I "render" hostvars based on the hostname?

Tags: ansible

The Ansible documentation gives an example [here](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_inventory.html) on how to return an inventory in JSON format:

```
{
    "databases"   : {
        "hosts"   : [ "host1.example.com", "host2.example.com" ],
        "vars"    : {
            "a"   : true
        }
    },
    "webservers"  : [ "host2.example.com", "host3.example.com" ],
    "atlanta"     : {
        "hosts"   : [ "host1.example.com", "host4.example.com", "host5.example.com" ],
        "vars"    : {
            "b"   : false
        },
        "children": [ "marietta", "5points" ]
    },
    "marietta"    : [ "host6.example.com" ],
    "5points"     : [ "host7.example.com" ]
}
```

and adding below that, that the hostvars for a single host can be set using:

```
{

    # results of inventory script as above go here
    # ...

    "_meta" : {
       "hostvars" : {
          "moocow.example.com"     : { "asdf" : 1234 },
          "llama.example.com"      : { "asdf" : 5678 },
       }
    }

}
```

Now I'm using Ansible 1.9.1 and would like to use hostvars or individual hosts. However, some of the hostvars follow a pattern. Most prominently `ansible_ssh_host` will follow a pattern `*.mydomain.tld`, there the wildcard gets replaced by the short hostname.

Is there a way to shorten the JSON by giving a pattern that will be rendered as a Jinja2 template, for example? Adjusting part of the above example:

```
{
    "atlanta"     : {
        "hosts"   : [ "host1", "host4", "host5" ],
        "vars"    : {
            "ansible_ssh_host" : "{{hostname}}.example.com",
            "b"   : false
        }
}
```

Anything *like* that possible with the format Ansible expects? I didn't find documentation mentioning this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `inventory_hostname` [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) in this case.

```
{
    "atlanta"     : {
        "hosts"   : [ "host1", "host4", "host5" ],
        "vars"    : {
            "ansible_ssh_host" : "{{inventory_hostname}}.example.com",
            "b"   : false
        }
}
```